# Usb 3.0 hub does not work with extender

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-hub

I have a TP-Link USB 3.0 4-Port Hub (UH400) and a Delock USB 3.0 cable, something similar to [this](http://dcp.lv/en/usb-30/15527-delock-cable-usb-30-a-extension-male-female-5m.html), but only 1m long.

They both work properly at least I tested both with an USB 3.0 Kingston pendrive. The results for Windows 7 are in the following list. (I can test them with Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04 too if necessary.)

- `motherboard -> pendrive` - ok
- `motherboard -> cable -> pendrive` - ok
- `motherboard -> HUB -> pendrive` - ok
- `motherboard -> cable -> HUB -> pendrive` - not ok

When I use the HUB with the cable the pendrive is usually not recognized, or it is recognized for a short time, I can see the files, but after a few seconds it shows me an empty drive with 0 bytes size.

I am not sure whether this is important, but I got several plugged in/out notifications when I use the HUB with the cable. At least I got that notification voice and according to the usbdeview something really happens in the background.

The USB 2.0 devices work properly. I can send data and charge them. The problem is with the USB 3.0 devices only. At least by this pendrive. I don't have any other USB 3.0 device.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Ramhound Why do you think this is a power issue?

Comment: @Ramhound The hub has only one short input cable. I did not get any extension cable with it and the shop did not mention anything about external cable. I am not sure about the power issue either, I can charge USB2 devices pretty well with it and transfer data as well, I have the problem only with the USB3 pendrive, which does not require much power.

Comment: @Ramhound As I already wrote, it works when I plug the pendrive directly into the motherboard, when I plug the pendrive into the extension cable and when I plug the pendrive into the HUB. The only scenario it does not work when I plug the pendrive into the HUB and the HUB into the extension cable. The HUB's input cable is too short, that's why I need an extension cable. Everything is USB 3.0. I am out of ideas... :S

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure. I already got driver issues by a camera using an extension cable different from the manufacturer's. So I think the problem is with the cable. Any idea how to tell? I don't have another extension cable or HUB. :S

Comment: I can't help you.  I will be removing my comments.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll go to a shop and ask them to check the hub and the cable. Worst case I buy another hub and give somebody in the family as a surprise.

Comment: @fixer1234 Ohh, sorry. My cable is only 1m length. I just linked a similar cable from an English page, since the shop is Hungarian. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Again; The problem isn't the cable.  Get a hub with an external power supply and it will work

Comment: @Ramhound And how do you explain that it works without the cable?

Comment: I appended my answer with experimental data, which show that **this is not a power delivery issue**. The hub+flash passes with 4.95V delivered on direct connection to Intel Host, but fails with 5.05V when connected behind another hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a motherboard related issue. The same hub with the same extender works properly on a different motherboard. I am not sure why.